# SQL sub queries - one alias column

Tags: mysql, sql

**course_completions**

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
|  id  coursemodid userid  state   timemodified |
+-----------------------------------------------+
|  370     23       2         1    1433582890   |
|  329     24       89        1    1427771915   |
|  333     30       39        1    1428309816   |
|  332     32       39        1    1428303307   |
|  327     33       40        1    1427689703   |
|  328     34       89        1    1427710711   |
|  303     35       41        1    1410258482   |
|  358     36       99        1    1432020067   |
|  365     25       2         1    1433142455   |
|  304     26       69        1    1410717866   |
|  353     37       95        1    1430387005   |
|  416     38       2         1    1438972465   |
|  300     27       70        1    1409824001   |
|  302     29       74        1    1412055704   |
|  297     30       2         1    1409582123   |
|  301     133      41        1    1410255923   |
|  336     133      91        1    1428398435   |
|  364     133      40        1    1433142348   |
|  312     133      85        1    1425863621   |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

**course_modules**

```
+------------------+
| id    course     |
+------------------+
| 23      6        |
| 24      6        |
| 25      6        |
| 26      6        |
| 27      6        |
| 28      6        |
| 29      8        |
| 30      8        |
| 31      8        |
| 32      8        |
| 33      8        |
| 34      5        |
| 35      5        |
| 36      5        |
| 37      5        |
| 38      5        |
| 39      9        |
| 40      9        |
| 41      9        |
+------------------+
```

**course_mod_settings**

```
+--------------------------------------+
|id  course  modinstance               |
+--------------------------------------+
| 27    8         30                   |
| 28    8         31                   |
| 29    8         32                   |
| 30    8         33                   |
| 31    6         23                   |
| 32    6         24                   |
| 33    6         25                   |
| 34    6         26                   |
| 35    6         27                   |
| 36    6         28                   |
| 37    9         39                   |
| 38    9         40                   |
| 39    9         41                   |
+--------------------------------------+
```

I was trying about to frame two sub queries in one SQL statement like I want the count of 'criteria mod settings' table values in one column and count of 'course_completions' table values in one column for a particular user along with course.

There shouldn't be relation between count(cms.id) and count(cc.id) except course id, because count(cms.id) is the count of user modules and  count(cc.id) is the settings count set by default.

OUTPUT:

```
COURSE        USERID     count(cms.id)     count(cc.id)
6               89             3              6
6               39             7              6
6               40             5              6
8               69             3              4
8               2              0              4
8               95             4              4
```

COURSE : getting courseid

USERID : getting userid

count(cms.id) : getting the count of user completed modules.

count(cc.id) : getting the count of settings (ex: For course 6, settings count has 6 and for course 4, settings count has 3.

```
SELECT cm.course
    ,cc.userid
    ,count(cc.coursemodid) AS usermodules
    ,(
        SELECT count(ccc.id)
        FROM course_mod_settings cms
        INNER JOIN course_modules cm ON cms.course = cm.course
        ) AS modsettings
FROM course_completions cc
INNER JOIN course_modules cm ON cc.coursemodid = cm.id
WHERE cc.STATE = 1
GROUP BY cm.cours
    ,cc.userid
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear, and also, please use the relevant tag for the rdbms you are working with.

Comment: @Zohar Peled - I had clearly explained the question in-detail. Could I know where didn't you get

Comment: Why can't you do a direct inner join on your `course_mod_settings` table?

Comment: @FutbolFan - I tried in that way too. We need to go with the course id so we can't directly INNER JOIN

Comment: @ronquiq Can you please explain the relationship between these three tables? And, also what you mean by `We need to go with the course id`?

Comment: @FutbolFan - 1st table is for getting users attempted no.of modules from a course - that courseid and moduleid are matching with id and course of 2nd table.  3rd table is no relation with no. of user modules, but only to get a default count modules set for that course.

Comment: Finally expecting a solution from Stack Overflow

Comment: @FutbolFan - You said to directly INNER JOIN course_mod_settings table. Could you elaborate your answer with a query

Comment: @ronquiq It's exactly the join in the answer you accepted below.

Comment: @ FutbolFan - I tried the below query with few modifications, It worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have read your comment above.

Have you tried something like this?

I didn't test the query, it's just a thought.
I might be wrong.

```
SELECT cms.course AS COURSE, cc.userid AS USERID, COUNT(cms.id), COUNT(cc.id) FROM
course_completions AS cc
INNER JOIN course_modules AS cm ON cc.coursemodid = cm.id
INNER JOIN course_mod_settings AS cms cm.course = cms.course
WHERE cc.state = 1
GROUP BY cm.course, cc.userid
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= cm.course = cms.course

Comment: There was one extra =. I deleted it. But I not sure about the query. May be it could lead you somewhere.